# Naturally sorting results of a scandir?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array containing the results of a scandir function. I've tried using the natsort() php function, but it doesn't appear to be working as I need it to for my directories.

The contents of the scanned directory assume a `HH(Z)DDMonYYYY` naming convention. After using the natsort function on the array, the result is this:

```
$dates = ["21Z23Oct2017", "20Z23Oct2017", "19Z23Oct2017", 
          "19Z18Oct2017", "19Z17Oct2017", "19Z16Oct2017",
          "18Z23Oct2017", "18Z18Oct2017", "17Z23Oct2017", ...]
```

As you can see, the function is evaluating the first two digits and using them to sort, but it ignores the days (23, 18, 17, 16) in each name.

I would like for the resulting array to look like this:

```
$dates = ["21Z23Oct2017", "20Z23Oct2017", "19Z23Oct2017", 
          "18Z23Oct2017", "17Z23Oct2017", ...,
          "19Z18Oct2017", "18Z18Oct2017", "19Z17Oct2017", "19Z16Oct2017"]
```

Since the directories are created sequentially, I realize that I could sort by directory creation or modification time and be just fine 99% of the time. However, on rare occasions the directories modification times will not be in perfect order, and I'd like to avoid problems when that is the case.

Is there a way to accomplish my goal in php without having to use modification or creation times?

Thanks to all in advance!

**EDIT**: for context, I'm using a Python script to write to and perform a simple operation on each of these directories. Python includes a package called "natsorted" for those unaware, which sorts the directories in the example array above without any trouble. Just wondering if there was a simple php solution as well before I start adding complexity.

Comment: How do you expect `natsort()` to parse your frankly bizarre date format?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment, @Sammitch! I don't know, actually, which is why I posted a question asking if it was possible

Answer (score 1):

All that `natsort()` does is try to address the sorting of strings with arbitrary-length digit sequences, it does not magically interpret bizarre date formats. Even the PHP functions that *do* try to figure out dates would not be able to figure this one out as they actually just use a predefined list of common formats and even *then* are problematic.

IMHO you should always use something like [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and an explicit format string.

```
<?php

$dates = ["21Z23Oct2017", "20Z23Oct2017", "19Z23Oct2017", 
          "19Z18Oct2017", "19Z17Oct2017", "19Z16Oct2017",
          "18Z23Oct2017", "18Z18Oct2017", "17Z23Oct2017"];

usort(
    $dates,
    function($a,$b){
        return DateTime::createFromFormat("H\ZdMY",$a) <=> DateTime::createFromFormat("H\ZdMY",$b);
    }
);

echo json_encode($dates, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
[
    "19Z16Oct2017",
    "19Z17Oct2017",
    "18Z18Oct2017",
    "19Z18Oct2017",
    "17Z23Oct2017",
    "18Z23Oct2017",
    "19Z23Oct2017",
    "20Z23Oct2017",
    "21Z23Oct2017"
]
```

This will work adequately for small sets of dates and/or when called infrequently. However if you're sorting a large number of dates, or sorting them frequently, you're going to want to pre-create the DateTime objects beforehand. As it stands both DateTimes in the comparison are recreated *for each comparison*.

Going forward, you should always format dates in a readable and *sortable* fashion, eg: `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`, ideally [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).