# Sort a series of vars

Tags: php, sorting, variables

How to sort this, from:

```
$res_events = "|2,20171021|1,20171007|2,20171007|1,20171028|2,20171014|1,20171014|2,20171028|1,20171021|";
```

to:

```
$res_events = "|1,20171007|1,20171014|1,20171021|1,20171028|2,20171007|2,20171014|2,20171021|2,20171028|";
```

Comment: Please describe what is changing, and how/why. Also please show how you tried to solve this.

Comment: @chris85 too late, he already got free code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode and sort array.
Then implode it back to string.

```
$res_events = "|2,20171021|1,20171007|2,20171007|1,20171028|2,20171014|1,20171014|2,20171028|1,20171021|";
$arr = explode("|", $res_events);

Sort($arr);
// Remove one of the two empty values in array
Unset($arr[0]);
// Implode and add last "|"
$new =implode("|", $arr)."|";
```

Output:

```
|1,20171007|1,20171014|1,20171021|1,20171028|2,20171007|2,20171014|2,20171021|2,20171028
```

https://3v4l.org/DIYYX

Comment: I got downvoted twice for responding to an unclear - incomplete question...

Comment: Ok.... I don't see it as unclear. Incomplete, yes it's missing attempts. But lots of questions do.

Comment: nope, that was when I started answering questions a while ago.  I am talking last 2 weeks.  I deleted the responses at that time.  Don't worry, I am still struggling with the "unwritten" rules applied here by different reviewers.

Comment: @Nic I don't know all the rules either. They seem to be different for each day.

Comment: This question should be *closed* because the author has not provided any evidence of even *attempting* to solve his own problem. Answers to these questions turn StackOverflow into a free coding and homework completion service.

Comment: @Sammitch where is the attempt in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899612/naturally-sorting-results-of-a-scandir/46899770#46899770

Comment: @Andreas in the text of the question, you pedant.

Answer (score 1):

See if this does the trick...

```
<?php // demo/temp_vincent.php
/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959713/sort-a-series-of-vars
 */
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo '<pre>';

// TEST DATA AND DESIRED RESULTS
$res_events = "|2,20171021|1,20171007|2,20171007|1,20171028|2,20171014|1,20171014|2,20171028|1,20171021|";
$chk_events = "|1,20171007|1,20171014|1,20171021|1,20171028|2,20171007|2,20171014|2,20171021|2,20171028|";

// TRIM OFF UNNECESSARY DELIMITERS
$res_events = trim($res_events, '|');

// MAKE AN ARRAY SO WE CAN SORT
$arr = explode('|', $res_events);
sort($arr);

// RECONSTRUCT THE STRING
$new_events = '|' . implode('|', $arr) . '|';

// TEST FOR SUCCESS
if ($new_events == $chk_events) echo 'Success!';
```